# Handling REST request with Message Queue

Tags: rest, spring-boot, apache-storm, mq

I have two applications as stated below:

1. Spring boot application - Acts as rest end point, publishes the request to message queue. ( Apache Pulsar )
2. Heron (Storm) topology - which processes the message received from  Message queue ( PULSAR ) and has all logic for processing.

My requirement, i need to serve different user queries through Spring boot application, which emits that query to message queue, and is consumed at spout. Once spout and bolts process the requests, a message is published again from bolt. That response from Bolt is handled at Spring boot (consumer) and replies to the user request. Typlically as shown below:

[image]

To serve to the same request, Im right now caching the deferred result object ( I set a reqID to each message which is sent to topology and  I also maintain a key, value pair for  )  in memory and when the message arrives I parse the request id and set the result to the defferedResult (I know this is a bad design, **HOW SHOULD ONE SOLVE THIS ISSUE ?**).

How can I proceed to serve the response back to the same request in this scenario where the order of messages received from topology is not sequential ( as each request which is processes takes its own time and producer bolt will fire the response as on when it is receives one ).

Im kind of stuck with this design and not able to proceed further.

```
//Controller
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> process(//someinput) {
    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> result = new DeferredResult<>(config.getTimeout());
    CompletableFuture<String> serviceResponse = service.processAsync(inputSource);
    serviceResponse.whenComplete((response, exception) -> {
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(exception))
            result.setErrorResult(//error);
        else
            result.setResult(//complete);
    });
    return result;
}

//In Service
public CompletableFuture processAsync(//input){
    producer.send(input);
    CompletableFuture result = new CompletableFuture();
    //consumer has a listener as shown below
    // **I want to avoid below line, how can I redesign this**
    map.put(id, result);
  return result;
}

//in same service, a listener is present for consumer for reading the messages
consumerListener(Message msg){
     int reqID = msg.getRequestID();
     map.get(reqID).complete(msg.getData);
}
```

> As shown above as soon as I get a message I get the completableFuture
>   object and set the result, which interally calls the defferred result
>   object and returns the response to the user.

Comment: I'm not sure why your question is targeting REST as you are looking for some internal solution. Next, you might consider encapsulating the invocation of the message queue into an own service in your Spring boot application which is [Spring cache](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) managed. Here spring caching will use AOP to cache method invocations based on a cache key (by default invoked method name + method arguments) and use this information on subsequent invocations to decide whether to return a previously cached value or send a new message to the queue and retrieve its response

Comment: HI @RomanVottner, thanks for the response, but I have added the code for better understanding. Can you please have a look. As I have to serve the user to the same request, Im caching the DefferedResult object and invoking that as on when I get respective message from other application.

Comment: Did you take a look at RMQ RPC(Remote Procedure Call) before? It creates a temporal response queue for each request so that consumer can consume message sequentially and produce response message asynchronously. Please refer to [Remote procedure call (RPC)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I proceed to serve the response back to the same request in this scenario where the order of messages received from topology is not sequential ( as each request which is processes takes its own time and producer bolt will fire the response as on when it is receives one ).

It sounds like you are looking for the [Correlation Identifier](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CorrelationIdentifier.html) messaging pattern.  In broad strokes, you compute/create an identifier that gets attached to the message sent to pulsar, and arrange that Heron copies that identifier from the request it receives to the response it sends.

Thus, when your Spring Boot component is consuming messages from pulsar at step 5, you match the correlation id to the correct http request, and return the result.

Using the original requestId() as your correlation identifier should be fine, as far as I can tell.

> To serve to the same request, Im right now caching the deferred result object ( I set a reqID to each message which is sent to topology and I also maintain a key, value pair for ) in memory and when the message arrives I parse the request id and set the result to the defferedResult (I know this is a bad design, HOW SHOULD ONE SOLVE THIS ISSUE ?).

Ultimately, you are likely to be doing that at some level; which is to say that the consumer at step 5 is going to be using the correlation id to look up *something* that was stored by the producer.  Trying to pass the original request across four different process boundaries is likely to end in tears.

The more general form is to store a *callback*, rather than a `CompletableFuture`, in the map; but in this case the callback probably just completes the future.

The one thing I would want to check carefully in the design: you want to be sure that the consumer at step 5 sees the future it is supposed to use before the message arrives.  In other words, there should be a happens-before memory barrier somewhere to ensure that the map lookup at step 5 doesn't fail.